# Pass named arguments in args field in py_binary

Tags: python-3.x, bazel, starlark

Consider I have a py_binary :

```
py_binary(
    name = "mock",
    srcs = ["mock.py"],
    args = [
        "$(location @mockref//mockpackage)",
    ],
    data = [
        "@mockref//:mockfile",
    ],
    deps = [
        requirement("somerequirement"),
    ],
)
```

If mock.py accept a command line argument named `--somearg` using argument parser how can I pass this argument through the args field in bazel file without passing the argument in `bazel build` command?

Answer (score 0):

The `args` attribute is only used with the `bazel run` command:

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/common-definitions.html#binary.args

To run a binary as part of a build, typically you'd use a `genrule` or a custom Starlark rule. Something like:

```
genrule(
  name = "gen_mock_output",
  outs = ["mock_output"],
  exec_tools = [":mock"],
  cmd = "$(location :mock) --output $@",
)
```

then you would build the output of the genrule:
`bazel build mock_output`

or use the output of the genrule as an input to another target